# Windows 10 connect to Azure AD Premium - Synchronisation not working

Tags: windows, azure, synchronization, windows-10, entra-id

I have a Windows 10 Client connected to AzureAD with my Work-Account. In addition I registered for the Premium AzureAD which allows me to have more features and functionality.

Now the issue is that I want to enable Synchronisation for example one particular user. First of all I need to assign users to the Microsoft Azure Active Directory Premium P2 license plan. After that I can enable directory features such as "Users may sync settings and enterprise app data". There I have chosen the SELECTED Box and put one of the users inside.

Now I expect when this user login into Windows 10 it should take the settings from AzureAD and enable this functionality. But it is not working. What needs to happen that this feature/settings are getting processed on the local client? Can we for example force this to be done with help of a command?

If you need further details, please let me know. Thanks a lot.

Cheers

Comment: You are better off raising a support ticket via the portal you use to configure the feature. You also need to clearly state how you determine the feature isn't working as expected.

Comment: I second @maweeras comment, how did figure out that it's not working? how can you tell that it's actually working? perhaps further reading here will help? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-windows-enterprise-state-roaming-overview/